# Bash script run app and get context console while app running

Tags: bash

Is it possible to run the program and get the contents of the console while the program is running.

```
run_res=($(/home/user/myapp))
```

if you run as above, then until the program finishes its work, I will not see the contents of the console.

Is it possible to see and pull out data during program startup?

Comment: You can run the command in the background but of course the assignment can't happen until it has stopped running. This is a common beginner FAQ; please search before asking.

Comment: Using an array assignment is weird here; did you really consciously mean to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the output of the program in the `run_res` variable, you can directly display it in the console using the `|` (pipe) operator.

```
/home/user/myapp | tee /dev/tty
```

and you can also replace `/dev/tty` with the desired file path if you want to save the output to a file!

**UPDATE**

according to your comment, you can try running your program in the background using the `&` operator like below:

```
/home/user/myapp | tee /dev/tty &
```

and if you want to continuously see the output of the program while it is running, you can try using the `unbuffer` (if available on your system) before executing the program, check it out

```
unbuffer /home/user/myapp
```

Comment: It didn't help, the program stops anyway and won't continue until you exit.
`
    run_res=""

    echo "Run $APPFILE..." > /dev/tty
    mqtt_send "Run $APPFILE" "$PRJ" "normal" "r"

    run_res=($(/home/user/myapp | tee /dev/tty)) 

    if [[ "$run_res" == "(full access):"* ]]; then 
        echo "$APPFILE running success! : $run_res" > /dev/tty
        exit 0
    fi
`

Comment: so you can try using the `unbuffer` let me update my answer

Comment: @Serjaru or using my previous method like this `/home/user/myapp | tee /dev/tty &` which means you can try running the program in the background using the `&` operator

Comment: unfortunately none of the options work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the output of the program running in the background just send it to a file and whenever you need it check its content

```
/home/usr/myapp > ~/tmp/myapp.out &
tail -f ~/tmp/myapp.out
```